# Typescript type enforcement

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript, and I'm a bit puzzled about why this code compiles correctly. `images` is an Array of strings, yet `this.data` is assigned and object where `images` is an Object.

```
declare type vd = {
    images: Array<string>;
}

class mytest {
   data: vd;

   constructor() {
     let obj = ['hello!', 'bye'];
     this.data = { images: { ...obj } };
     console.log(this.data.images);
   }
}
```

As expected, this is printed on the console:

> Object 0: "hello!" 1: "bye"

Changing the curly braces for regular braces, prints the following:

> Array(2) 0: "hello!" 1:"bye" length: 2

Why isn't the compiler complaining on the assignment of `this.data` in the first case?

Comment: I would say this is a borderline bug. You can spread an array into an object and back and forth, but they are not isomorphic and both directions are lossy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript and typescript, arrays are objects, so with you `obj` variable initialized as array, this pointless operation is valid and allowed - as Aluan Haddad said in the comment, you can spread array (which is an object) into an object:

```
    {...obj}
```

To reveal what type it produces, you can add [this pointless assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20type%20vd%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20images%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20mytest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20data%3A%20vd%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20obj%20%3D%20%5B'hello!'%2C%20'bye'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20r%3A%20void%20%3D%20%7B%20...obj%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20this.data%20%3D%20%7B%20images%3A%20%7B%20...obj%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.data.images)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) and watch the error message:

```
const r: void = { ...obj }
```

> Type '{ [n: number]: string; length: number; toString(): string;
>   toLocaleString(): string; push(...item...' is not assignable to type
>   'void'.

See, as a result of spread, the type of `{...obj}` looks just like an array, it has [indexable by number signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), and it has all properties and methods that array has, so, by TypeScript structural compatibility rules, it's assignable to an array - that's why there is no error in your code.

This is different from what you would get in javascript at runtime. Non-enumerable properties of the array would not be copied to an object, and the result would have only two properties that come from array indexes - `"1"` and `"2"`.

This is a shortcoming of TypeScript type system - there is no way to account for non-enumerable properties, they are treated as if they were enumerable like all other properties. If there were, this assignment would have produced an error.

Comment: Thanks. I came to this issue because in the first case, `this.data.images.length` is undefined, which is an issue when trying to iterate through the Array. Shouldn't that assignment fail, when all Arrays have such a property?

Comment: If you open [mdn for Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) and scroll it down you will find a table that says that `Array.length` is non-enumerable property. That means it's not copied when you assign array properties to an object with `Object.assign` or object spread - these operations [copy enumerable properties only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: Typescript does not know that properties can be non-enumerable, and the result of `Object.assign` and object spread is typed incorrectly if the source object has some non-enumerable properties. Ideally, that assignment should be flagged as error by typechecker, but it would be possible only when it will be possible to declare some properties of a type as non-enumerable  in TypeScript.